# Defining OpenStruct attribute with same name as instance method

Tags: ruby, openstruct

I'm running into an issue when trying to create an open struct with an attribute that has the same name as one of the OpenStruct instance methods. Specifically, i'd like to create an open struct that has an attribute `capture`. I'm using this as a stub in an rspec test, so i can't change the name of the method (it must be `capture`)

```
#=> OpenStruct.new(capture: true).capture 
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

looking at the OpenStruct methods, it has a method `capture` and it is this method that is getting called. Is there a way to instantiate an open struct with an attribute of the same name as one of its methods?

for clarity, i specifically need the method capture, which i've confirmed breaks on rails 4.0.x but not rails 5, but this situation holds true for any method openstruct might have.

```
#=> OpenStruct.new(class: true).class 
#=> OpenStruct
```

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me in `pry` (running ruby 2.3, by the way)

```
[9] pry(main)> OpenStruct.new(capture: 1).capture
=> 1
```

Here's another way to do it:

```
[15] pry(main)> a = OpenStruct.new capture: 1
=> #<OpenStruct capture=1>
[22] pry(main)> a.singleton_class.class_exec { def capture; self[:capture] + 1; end }
=> :capture
[23] pry(main)> a.capture
=> 2
```

i don't know what testing library you're using, but if it's RSpec, you could use this mocking approach as well:

```
a = OpenStruct.new capture: 0
allow(a).to receive(:capture).and_return(a[:capture])
a.capture # => 0
```

Comment: it works fine for me on rails 5 but not rails 4. if you use the method `class` it still uses the openstruct instance method, not the attribute i define

Comment: what do you mean "if you use the method `class`"?

Comment: if you define the attribute `class` instead of `capture`, it uses the open struct instance method `class`, not the attribute i define. i've edited my question for clarity

Comment: it's the same situation. did you try my advice for an alternate approach?

Comment: Anyway, I don't really see why this is worth the trouble. You can just use `[:class]` to access it anyway right?